# Como faço para usar as funções if e else?

Tags: python, condição

Estou com problemas nas funções `if` e `else`, comecei meus estudos de programação a pouco tempo e não entendi muito bem como usar.

É algo assim?

```
número = 2
If número == 2:
Print("esse número é 2")
Else:
Print("esse número é diferente de 2")
```

Answer (score 4):

Para começar, é bom saber que `if` e `else` não são funções. Elas são o que chamamos de **estruturas de seleção condicional**. O exemplo que você mostrou está correto (exceto pela indentação e pelas iniciais maiúsculas no if e no else).

Caso você queira apenas fazer algo caso uma condição seja verdadeira, use o `if`

```
# código que vem antes
if 3 < 5:
    print("Três é menor que 5")
#código que vem depois
```

Caso queira fazer algo caso uma condição seja verdadeira e algo diferente caso seja falsa, use o `if ... else`:

```
umaVerdade = True

if umaVerdade:
    print("É verdade")
else:
    print("Não é verdade")
```

Caso tenha vários casos a considerar, use também o `elif`

```
entrada = input("Digite uma letra")

if entrada == "A" or entrada == "a":
    print("Você digitou a primeira letra do alfabeto português")
elif entrada == "Z" or entrada == "z":
    print("Você digitou a última letra do alfabeto português")
else:
    print("Você digitou uma coisa meio desinteressante")
```

Repare que tem um `else` no final. Antes dele podem vir quantos `elif` forem necessários para cobrir todos os casos com tratamentos específicos.

Comment: Obrigado,eu estava com dúvida nisso.

Comment: No exemplo dele não só a identação - mas o uso de maiúsculas e minusculas está errado também. `if`, `else` e todas as palavras chave do Python são escritas com letras minúsculas.

Comment: Verdade. Infelizmente trabalho com uma variante de VB. Essa coisa pega, rs.